# Unable to launch Java JNLP application after downloading

Tags: java, jar, java-web-start, jnlp

I would like to include my java application which I save it as jar file inside web browser. I've tried the Java Web Start tutorial and create the Java JNLP application. I also follow tutorials based on here: http://transvar.org/6112/WebStartAppInstruction.pdf

I've tried all the steps but after I download the Launch.jnlp and try to launch it error such "Unable to Launch the application" pop up. I clicked the Details button to check where did I done wrong.

Here's the error (Exception tab):

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: file:/C:/Users/nurulazila/Documents/NetBeansProjects/fyp_steganalysis/dist/$$codebase/launch.jnlp
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.updateFinalLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Wrapped Exception Tab:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\nurulazila\Documents\NetBeansProjects\fyp_steganalysis\dist\$$codebase\launch.jnlp (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequestEX(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.updateFinalLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My code (Launch.jnlp):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="$$codebase" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>fyp_steganalysis</title>
        <vendor>nurulazila</vendor>
        <homepage href="www.google.com"/>
        <description>fyp_steganalysis</description>
        <description kind="short">fyp_steganalysis</description>
    </information>
    <update check="always"/>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+"/>
        <jar href="fyp_steganalysis.jar" main="true"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="steganalysisUI">
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Launch.HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test page for launching the application via JNLP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Test page for launching the application via JNLP</h3>
        <script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
        <script>
            deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton("launch.jnlp")
        </script>
        <!-- Or use the following link element to launch with the application -->
        <!--
        <a href="launch.jnlp">Launch the application</a>
        -->
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm really new to Java JNLP. Hoping to get some help here.

Comment: The issue is your codebase. Note that with recent versions of jnlp specs you don't need to specify it. So removing the codebase attribute in your jnlp and changing the spec to 7.0+ may solve your issue.

Comment: @assylias I've tried your approach. When I clicked the Launch.jnlp itself the application pop up error "the application is blocked something ..." . I guess it must got to do with Java setting. But when I downloading it from browser the "Unable to launch the application" pop up again. I don't know what to do now.

Comment: Are you launching with a Java 7 JRE? When you get errors such as "Unable to launch the application" you should have a link like "more info" which contains useful information for troubleshooting.

Comment: The "blocked" message is a different problem.  Open your Java control panel, go to the Security tab, and either set the security level to Medium, or add the URL of the machine which hosts your JNLP file (which may be just `file:///`) to the Exception Site List.  Or, you could buy a code signing certificate and sign your .jar file with it, but there is a bit of a learning curve for that.

Answer (score 1):

As per linked document, You need to edit it to locate the codebase of your application.i.e

```
<jnlp codebase="http://webpages.uncc.edu/~acenglis" href="launch.jnlp"/>
```

I don't see that you have followed the tutorial completely (especially editing your jnlp file)

Comment: where is such tutorial?

Comment: I said the link in the question